# JSONObject value null check failed with empty() and ==null why

Tags: java, json

I am having following json

```
{"signature": null, "state": "eyJjc3OiIifQ", "tokenId": null, "error": "EXCEPTION_REQUEST_CANCELLED"}
```

from `jsonObject`  of `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(authMeta);`

I tried checking

```java
if(jsonObject.get("signature") == null) {} else {}
```

condition IF failed and code went to else block. tried another method

```java
if(jsonObject.get("signature").toString().isEmpty())
```

Above also failed.

```java
if(jsonObject.get("signature").equals(null))
```

Worked.

Following code worked.

```java
jsonObject.isNull("signature")
```

I checked inside isNull Method, i found following.

```java
public boolean isNull(String key) {
    return JSONObject.NULL.equals(this.opt(key));
}
```

Unable to understand why null is different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `org.json.JSONObject.get(java.lang.String key)` is going to return `java.lang.Object`.
So...

```
jsonObject.get("signature") == null
```

This doesn't work because `==` in Java is used to compare primitives and objects. And `==` compare two objects based on memory reference. so `==` operator will return true only if two object reference it is comparing represent exactly same object.

```
jsonObject.get("signature").equals(null)
```

This works because we use the `equals()` method to compare objects in Java. In order to determine if two objects are the same, `equals()` compares the values of the objects’ attributes.

Let's look at following example:

```
System.out.println(obj.get("signature").getClass()); //class org.json.JSONObject$Null
System.out.println(obj.get("state").getClass()); //class java.lang.String

System.out.println(JSONObject.NULL.getClass()); //class org.json.JSONObject$Null
```

You can see that the first statement returns a `Object` and the second one returns a `String`. That's why you using `equals()` for null check works.